# how to deallocate memory in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class A where I construct an object of class B named bb. 
After constructing the object bb, I run in to a exception in Class A code which is caught by an exception handler. 
Now my question is how to deallocate the memory of object B in the exception handler?

Comment: It might be helpful to post some code.  I don't understand why you can't simply deallocate object B in the exception handler by calling `delete`.

Comment: Object B should be allocated using a smart pointer, so you don't even need to worry about deallocating it in the event of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use `shared_ptr`

```
struct B {...};

struct A {
  A() : bb(new B) {} // auto-deallocate
  boost::shared_ptr<B> bb;
}
```

Comment: Using `boost::make_shared` instead of `new` is even more exception safe (not perhaps in this example), use less memory, and is a tad faster.

Answer (score 0):

If the class B object is the member object of class A(aggregate pattern), then you don't even need deallocate it explicitly as long as B itself is RAII-ed. On the other hand, if it's a heap object( A dynamically allocates bb on heap), you need explicitly release it. You can either use boost::scoped_ptr or boost::shared_ptr(depending on whether you want bb's ownship to be shared with others) to hold the ownship of object bb so that it'll get released automatically when class A object is deleted.